# Where can I find a shower door with a corner clipped to match my ceiling?

Tags: doors, shower, glass

I am working on adding a shower in the attic. The hard part is that the attic ceiling is at an angle, and I am looking to find options for the shower door. Could anyone suggest any solutions to that?

Home Depot has rectangular tempered glass panels, but I found they can't be cut and I can't use annealed glass as per code. Are there any other options for shower doors?

Below is the shape of the door that I'm looking to use. [image: Shower Door Shape]

Comment: They will make tempered-glass custom units if you go to a specialty shop (defs not HD or other big-box store). I know, I used to sell them. Have you considered a shower curtain as the low $$ option?

Comment: @JimmyFix-it - they have options like this in big box online and things like overstock.com.    Also you could just think about the door height ending at the angle.

Comment: Look up "custom glass" in Google Maps.   Assuming your attic, like most, is cramped and the shower stall is not huge, it will be nice for the users to have a door rather than a curtain intruding, and the cost of this might uplift the whole attic living experience and be worth it.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider a longer shower base - we found one about 1.2m long and 80 wide which meant we did not need a door at all as there was very little splash out.

And we had this with a sloped ceiling as well, the shower head had to be in the top corner as I am 6ft plus - for my (ex)wife that was not an issue.